# How to register a user via. endpoint in Keycloak?

Tags: rest, curl, keycloak, openid-connect

I want to provide a registration form in my web application that allows users to register. The form data should then be sent per endpoint a keycloak (I use openid-connect) and the user should be registered.

I've already tried the endpoint {host}/auth/realms/{rrealm}/protocol/openid-connect/registrations, but it doesn't find this page.

Is there any way to do this and is there an other endpoint?

Comment: With keycloak you can use Admin API https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_users